# How to display data from database in new window in php

Tags: php

I have created register form using php.

I want to display, current registered user details in new window.

Here is my data.php:

```
    <?php
    include('config.php');

       $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM crop ORDER BY id DESC");
    $result->execute();
while( $row = $result->fetch()){

    $fname = $row['fname']; 
    $lname = $row['lname']; 
    $email = $row['email']; 
    $pass = $row['pass']; 
    $phone = $row['phone']; 
    $sex_select = $row['sex_select']; 
    $month = $row['month']; 
    $day = $row['day']; 
    $year = $row['year']; 
    $id = $row['id']; 

    }
    ?>
    <html>

<body>

<from >
  <table  style="color:purple;border-style:groove; height:150px;width:350px" background="3.jpg">

        <tr>

            <td style="font-family:Copperplate Gothic Bold">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Id no:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text1" type="text" value='<?php echo  $id; ?>'/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">FirstName:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text2" type="text" value='<?php echo  $fname; ?>'/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">LastName:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text3" type="text" value='<?php echo  $lname; ?>' /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Email:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text4" type="text" value='<?php echo  $email; ?>' /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Password:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text5" type="text" value='<?php echo  $pass; ?>' /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

           <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Contact Number:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text6" type="text" value='<?php echo  $phone; ?>' ></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Sex_Select:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text7" type="text" value='<?php echo  $sex_select; ?>'/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Month:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text8" type="text" value='<?php echo  $month; ?>' /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Day:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text9" type="text"  value='<?php echo  $day; ?>'/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;" class="auto-style3">Year:</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">

                <input id="Text10" type="text" value='<?php echo  $year; ?>'/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td></td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

And i include data.php file in index.php.

Now it shows, http://s28.postimg.org/ndbnjlyz1/Untitled_1_copy.png

Can anyone help me with us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Patience is key when you ask questions on SO. Chances are, you will get a good answer but you just need to be patient.

Comment: If the local variables you're creating are necessary because they're needed in other included files, please specify that; it only causes confusion otherwise. At that point, they should global variables, not local variables.

Comment: You had a similar question closed due to it being unclear as to what you wanted. Please elaborate on what you want. Your current question has functional code.

Comment: So you want it to redirect to a page with the information after registration?

Comment: I'm also deleting my answer as it too is pointless. Please be clear as to what you are asking. Ronser's answer is appropriate.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123: please see this link, and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419184/how-to-insert-data-into-database-using-pdo-in-php?noredirect=1#comment41484901_26419184

Answer (score 0):

this could be done the moment you insert in to your database

```
   //use
    session_start(); //then

        $v1="'" . $conn->real_escape_string('col1_value') . "'";

    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl (col1_varchar, col2_number) VALUES ($v1,10)";

    if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else {
      $_SESSION['user_id']  = $conn->insert_id;  //get the id in a session variable
    }

    //redirect to another page say user_details.php  and show the result using the session...

   header("location:user_details.php");
```

make a edit in the query

```
   $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM crop 
                          WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                          ORDER BY id DESC");  //this brings the data of the last entered user.
```

Comment: it seems your code takes all the values from the database instead of the last user loggedin..

Comment: can you help me, to fix this?

Comment: is your database connectivity executes successfully?? at what stage are you now?? have you used session before??

Comment: then use session to pass the id from the signup page to the user details page `header("location:user_details.php");` can be used to redirect once the user has successfully completes the signin process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63087/discussion-between-ronser-and-user4119973).